# MDM iOS Enterprise app distribution

Tags: ios, mdm, ios-provisioning, ios-enterprise

We have different enterprise applications distributed via Airwatch MDM. When some distribution profile was expiring after 1 year earlier we could see a popup on the iOS devices. Now its not showing due to some reason. I'm not sure why. Also I can't find the profiles section in the iOS 8 settings section. There it used to show the expiration dates for all the profiles.

If the developer is not noticing the expiration date, apps getting crashed after the expiration date.

I want to know the best optimum solution for this.

How do we get the notifications for this?

Is there any solution without redistributing a new binary?

Or do we have any reminder notification system for this?

Comment: Which MDM are you using?

Comment: We are using Airwatch MDM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the provisioning profile without redistributing a new binary.  If you go to the app and click on the "files" tab and select "edit" this will allow you to upload the new profile.

Comment: I can accept this as a correct answer. one more thing. How can I get the prior notifications for this. As I remember in earlier iOS version we got reminder popups saying its going to expire in x days.

Comment: There is no way to get the reminder popup as Apple has purposely removed it as it served no purpose for the every day user and bothered thousands just to save the administrator the bother of setting their own reminders if they wanted to update the profile and preempt expiration.  See WWDC 2014 "Managing Apple Devices" for more info on Apple's "don't show/bother users on provisioning profiles" philosophy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to tackle your questions with in-line answers:

> If the developer is not noticing the expiration date, apps getting crashed after the expiration date.

Speaking frankly it's up to your Enterprise Agent to maintain and track when provisioning profiles are expiring. Likewise they should be planning your required yearly release in conjuncion with the expiring profile. It is not the developer's job to maintain that part of the app development process unless you're specifically paying them to do so.

> How do we get the notifications for this?

See above. All profile expiration dates are in your Enterprise Portal.

> Is there any solution without redistributing a new binary?

This won't always work, especially if your Enterprise Distribution cert is also expiring. If your Enterprise Cert expires you MUST deploy a newly signed binary.